# Converting "range" type to "integer" in Visual Basic .NET

Tags: vb.net, excel-interop

I wrote this codes in vb.net. I want to use this function to plot a simple mathematics operation but this error appears during the compilation. 
Please help me to correct that..

```
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Public Class Form1
    Function ExcelReader(ByVal Address As String, ByVal SheetName As String, ByVal StartRow As Integer, ByVal EndRow As Integer, ByVal StartColumn As Integer, ByVal EndColumn As Integer) As String(,)
        Dim Contents(EndRow - StartRow + 1, EndColumn - StartColumn + 1) As String
        Dim ExcelInterface As New Excel.Application
        Dim Workbook As Excel.Workbook
        Dim Sheet As Excel.Worksheet

        Workbook = ExcelInterface.Workbooks.Open("address")
        Sheet = Workbook.Sheets(SheetName)

        For Row As Integer = StartRow To EndRow
            For Column As Integer = StartColumn To EndColumn
                Contents(Row - StartRow, Column - StartColumn) = Sheet.Cells(Row, Column)
            Next
        Next

        Return Contents
    End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read the value of the range this way:

```
DirectCast(Sheet.Cells(Row, Column), Excel.Range).Value
```

Or simply this way:

```
Sheet.Cells(Row, Column).Value
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this alternate would be acceptable. Note that all objects used are disposed of properly which leads to more code in the long run.

Example call

```
Dim demo As New ExcelIterate With
    {
        .FileName = IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Countries.xlsx"),
        .SheetName = "countrylist"
    }
Dim results As Object(,) = demo.OpenExcelIterate("A9", "B15")
```

Class

```
Option Strict On
Option Infer Off

Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Imports Microsoft.Office
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Public Class ExcelIterate
    Public Property FileName As String
    Public Property SheetName As String

    Public Function OpenExcelIterate(ByVal StartCell As String, ByVal LastCell As String) As Object(,)

        Dim Results(,) As Object = Nothing

        If IO.File.Exists(FileName) Then

            Dim Proceed As Boolean = False
            Dim xlApp As Excel.Application = Nothing
            Dim xlWorkBooks As Excel.Workbooks = Nothing
            Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook = Nothing
            Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet = Nothing
            Dim xlWorkSheets As Excel.Sheets = Nothing
            Dim xlCells As Excel.Range = Nothing

            xlApp = New Excel.Application
            xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
            xlWorkBooks = xlApp.Workbooks
            xlWorkBook = xlWorkBooks.Open(FileName)

            xlApp.Visible = False

            xlWorkSheets = xlWorkBook.Sheets

            For x As Integer = 1 To xlWorkSheets.Count
                xlWorkSheet = CType(xlWorkSheets(x), Excel.Worksheet)

                If xlWorkSheet.Name = SheetName Then
                    Proceed = True
                    Exit For
                End If

                Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(xlWorkSheet)
                xlWorkSheet = Nothing

            Next
            If Proceed Then

                Dim xlUsedRange As Excel.Range = xlWorkSheet.Range(StartCell, LastCell)
                Dim DecimalTest As Decimal = 0

                Try
                    Results = CType(xlUsedRange.Value(Excel.XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault), Object(,))
                Finally
                    ReleaseComObject(xlUsedRange)
                End Try

            Else
                MessageBox.Show(SheetName & " not found.")
            End If

            xlWorkBook.Close()
            xlApp.UserControl = True
            xlApp.Quit()

            ReleaseComObject(xlCells)
            ReleaseComObject(xlWorkSheets)
            ReleaseComObject(xlWorkSheet)
            ReleaseComObject(xlWorkBook)
            ReleaseComObject(xlWorkBooks)
            ReleaseComObject(xlApp)
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("'" & FileName & "' not located. Try one of the write examples first.")
        End If

        Return Results

    End Function

    Private Sub ReleaseComObject(ByVal obj As Object)
        Try
            If obj IsNot Nothing Then
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj)
                obj = Nothing
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            obj = Nothing
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```